# SignalR Vs Google Cloud messaging Vs Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, signalr, google-cloud-messaging, mobile-application

We have a .Net based backed server and want to push messages/notifications to Mobile clients.  At first we start with the google cloud messaging but it sometimes take extra time to send message. Now we are planning to use signal R but didn't know whether it will be a good move or not. Please recommend according to your experience and help to choose the best one of them for the push messages and notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Go for google cloud messaging. signalR will require a constant connection to the back end. so you will have to keep a service running in the background just to get push notification. This is a bad practice as it eats up battery. so go for GCM.

Comment: but we have a back-end server in .Net and we have to implement the messaging /notifications service on web too. And signalR is the best library to implement this thing on web. what you say?

Comment: My friends suggest me to implement Google cloud messaging on android side and leave the back-end work to signalR. means google cloud messaging will communicate with SignalR backend...Is it possible or make sence? @Bill gates

Comment: use SignalR to show Notification on the web and GCM in android.

Comment: please answer to my second comment too...Thanks

Comment: i don't know about the server side of signalR.

Comment: you can used signalR in native android too and for me is the best if you have your own hosting and server GCM with firebase power is good and easy to apply